# Cell value change based on other cell

Tags: excel, vba, validation, excel-formula

for testcase purposes I have created an excel with test steps.
For every test step there is a 'status' cell, possible values are 'To Do,Passed, Failed, Incomplete'. 
What I want to do is when I select 'Failed' for a step, the following steps below with value 'To Do' are automatically changed to 'Incomplete'. 
I don't know why I can't find a clear solution for this so sorry if it's easier than the general level of questions asked here.

Comment: Please give us some examples of data and anything that you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have drop-down lists assigned for each cell in the "Status" column. This code assumes that column's range is c1:c7, which you should change to whatever your range is.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal responses As Range)


Set responses = Range("c1:c7")

For Each r In responses.Rows
    If Cells(r.Row, 3).Value = "Failed" Then
        For i = r.Row To responses.Rows.Count
            If Cells(i, 3) = "To Do" Then
                Cells(i, 3) = "Incomplete"
            End If
        Next i
    End If
 Next r

End Sub
```

Good luck

Comment: A variation of this worked, thanks.